# Photo profile picture

Tags: react-native

### SOLVED

I can shot photo picture, print on the screen and successfully upload on the server. But just after re-visiting profile page default picture doesn't shown

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.shotPhoto.bind(this)}>
  <Image style={{ height: 200, width: 150 }} source={{ uri: this.props.userpicture } == { uri: 'http://webstudio.web.tr/resimler/resimyok.png' } ? { uri: 'http://webstudio.web.tr/resimler/kullaniciresmi/' + this.state.email + '.jpeg' } : { uri: this.props.userpicture }} />
  <Text style={{ height: 50, width: 150, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>Shot a photo</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

[image: Photo after camera shot, profile owner photo shown successfully]
[image: First visit of the page not shown the picture of profile owner]

The complate source code of my project is at https://github.com/EnginYilmaz/kpbduser/blob/master/src/user/HesabimForm.js

(Yes, it is important for me to give me any idea)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of exact problems but here you compare object with another object which will always be false regardless of `userpicture` value:

```
{ uri: this.props.userpicture } == { uri: 'http://webstudio.web.tr/resimler/resimyok.png' } ? { uri: 'http://webstudio.web.tr/resimler/kullaniciresmi/' + this.state.email + '.jpeg' } : { uri: this.props.userpicture }
```

Try to compare URLs instead:

```
this.props.userpicture == 'http://webstudio.web.tr/resimler/resimyok.png' ? { uri: 'http://webstudio.web.tr/resimler/kullaniciresmi/' + this.state.email + '.jpeg' } : { uri: this.props.userpicture }
```

Comment: The code is not working at the moment thank you giving idea about objec comparing.

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround my solution is:

```
isShotPhoto () {
if (!this.props.userpicture ) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.shotPhoto.bind(this)}>
      <Image style={{ height: 200, width: 150 }} source={{ uri:'http://webstudio.web.tr/resimler/kullaniciresmi/'+this.state.email+'.jpeg' }} />
      <Text style={{ height: 50, width: 150, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>Fotoğrafınızı çekin</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );
} else {
  return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.shotPhoto.bind(this)}>
    <Image style={{ height: 200, width: 150 }} source={{ uri:this.props.userpicture  }} />
    <Text style={{ height: 50, width: 150, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>Fotoğrafınızı çekin</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

}